# What documents are needed for an EU permanent resident to work in Netherlands?

Tags: working-visas, eu, netherlands

Assuming one is a permanent resident of an EU state other than Netherlands (e.g. Czech Republic), what documents are needed for them to work in Netherlands? The Dutch Immigration and Naturalisation Service [mentions](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/long-term-third-country-nationals) that:

> If you have been granted the status of long-term resident-EC in
>   another EU Member state, and you wish to move to the Netherlands, you
>   will be exempt from the mvv requirement. You  or your sponsor can then
>   apply for a residence permit directly upon arrival in the Netherlands.
>   Your sponsor can also submit the application while you are not yet in
>   the Netherlands. You will have to choose a purpose of stay and meet
>   the conditions accordingly.

However it isn't clear if an EU resident can start working in Netherlands without any additional documents and *then* apply for a residency if deciding to stay for more than three months.

An equivalent Czech law mentions that it's possible to work without a visa if the person in question has been a permanent resident of the EU for more than 1 year. Unfortunately I don't know enough Dutch to dig up the equivalent Netherlands law.

Comment: Relevant: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/what-documents-are-needed-for-an-eu-permanent-resident-to-work-in-germany. I would like to create a collection of questions for the 25 participants of the EU permanent residents directive, as this information is extremely hard to find online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my case, I'm Syrian and I have a resident permit to EU issued from Portugal because I was a student there. I got a job in the Netherlands, my employer applied for my MVV visa and working permit in the same application. My employer is a recognized sponsor by IND. You still need the MVV but the difference is that you don't need to put a sticker on your passport **before** coming to the Netherlands since you're already allowed to enter the Netherlands due to your other EU residence card. You'd need to have an appointment in IND, there they'll put the sticker on your passport and take your fingerprints and after a week or so, they'll send you your residence card.

The only required documents they asked for are: passport, job contract, and your other EU card. Please be aware that later on your employer may ask for a criminal record and when you register in the municipality you need a birth certificate.

I'd also advise you to bring any document to state your previous address so you can take your BSN (citizenship security number) even before having rented a property in the Netherlands

I hope that helps you

Comment: Did you need to give up your Portuguese card in order to get the Dutch one?

Comment: @JonathanReez no, I have both cards, but the Portuguese one will expire soon