# What documents are needed for an EU permanent resident to work in Sweden?

Tags: eu, resident-permit, sweden

Assuming one is a permanent resident of an EU state other than Sweden (e.g. Czech Republic), what documents are needed for them to work in Sweden? The Swedish Migration Agency [mentions](http://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/EU-citizens-and-long-term-residents/Long-term-residents.html) that:

> If you have previously held long-term resident status in another EU country and now fulfil the requirements for long-term resident status in Sweden, you may apply to transfer the status from the other country to Sweden.

This raises the following questions:

1. Is it possible to start working in Sweden and *then* apply for a Swedish residence permit? Or do you have to apply for one in advance?
2. What does "transfer the status" mean? Are you going to lose your old EU permanent residency card when you receive your Swedish one?
3. What documents are needed to apply for a residency permit for the purpose of work? Is a work contract sufficient?
4. How long does the process of receiving a Swedish residency card take for EU residents?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/what-documents-are-needed-for-an-eu-permanent-resident-to-work-in-germany and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/what-documents-are-needed-for-an-eu-permanent-resident-to-work-in-netherlands

Comment: You do realize that this is controlled by an EU directive, don't you?  I don't see the point of having a different question for each country.

Comment: @phoog the rules are a bit different for each country and it helps to know the *specifics*, rather than the general description. For Germany it took me a few hours of searching and I still couldn't find the exact rules until a German speaker came along here on Expats.

Comment: @Crazydre may have insight, particularly on 1, 3, and 4